# If I have RDD[(String, String)], how can I save first element of tuple into one file and store second elements into another file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using the Spark saveasTextfile API and I don't know how to store tuples into two different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create two RDDs and save them individually.

```
val rdd1 = rdd.map(_._1)
val rdd2 = rdd.map(_._2)
rdd1.saveAsTextFile("file1")
rdd2.saveAsTextFile("file2")
```

Comment: BTW, if my dataset is really large, whether these kind of operations will decrease efficiency dramatically?

Comment: @RuofeiShen writing to a single file with both the fields of Tuple is efficient compared to writing two files each with a single field of the Tuple. But if your requirement is to have two separate files with each fields then you use the above approach..

Comment: @RuofeiShen You could also use a `.foreach` and write to both files with one loop, but the above could be combined with [`Futures`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) and run in parallel.